Type error: cannot read the properties of undefined style
This is the image of the code I am trying to get solved.

I am trying to set the cursor Img opacity to 1 but it is saying error.
When I go to the inspect mode and refresh it it works fine but when I reload the page existing the inspect mode gives me the same error.
And I am using locomotive js. After removing locomotive js it works fine no errors are coming.

when you are reload the page cardHoverEffect() function is run before your DOM load and this is the reason for type error cannot read property
